# Typecasting from one class to another isnot working

Tags: c++, static-cast

Conversion from `SI` to `ImperialSystem` is working but the reverse isnot working.
The error message:
`static_cast: cannot convert from ImperialSystem to SI`

code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#define endl '\n'
using std::cout;
#define MTRTOFEETRATIO 3.28084;

/*
Write two classes to store distances in meter-centimeter and feet-inch systems respectively. Write conversions functions so that the program can convert
objects of both types.
*/
class SI;
class ImperialSystem {
private:
    int mfeet;
    int minch;
public:
    ImperialSystem(int m, int cm) :mfeet{ m }, minch{ cm }{};
    ImperialSystem(float dis) :mfeet{ static_cast<int>(dis) }, minch{ static_cast<int>((dis - mfeet) * 12) } {}
    operator float() {
        return mfeet + minch / 12.0;
    }
    operator SI();
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const ImperialSystem& dis);
};

class SI {
private:
    int mmeter;
    int mcentimeter;
public:
    SI(int m, int cm) :mmeter{ m }, mcentimeter{ cm }{};
    SI(float dis) :mmeter{ static_cast<int>(dis) }, mcentimeter{ static_cast<int>((dis - mmeter) * 12) } {}
    operator ImperialSystem();
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const SI& dis);
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const SI& dis) {
    out << " " << dis.mmeter << " m " << dis.mcentimeter << " cm ";
    return out;
}
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const ImperialSystem& dis) {
    out << " " << dis.mfeet << " ft " << dis.minch << " in ";
    return out;
}
ImperialSystem::operator SI() {
    double feet = mfeet + minch / 12;
    double meter = feet / MTRTOFEETRATIO;
    return meter;
}
SI::operator ImperialSystem() {
    double meter = mmeter + mcentimeter / 100.0;
    double feet = meter * MTRTOFEETRATIO;
    return feet;
}


int main() {
    SI s{ 20,35 };
    cout << s << " =  " << static_cast<ImperialSystem>(s) << endl;//this works
    ImperialSystem i{ 10,11 };
    cout << i << " =  " << static_cast<SI>(i) << endl;//but this doesnot

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your code [compiles as written on GCC trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/61TYjv4Gr). What compiler and standard version are you using?

Comment: Your `operator float` on `ImperialSystem` probably makes constructor ambiguous.

Comment: That code lacks a ton of `const` qualifiers. Add `const` to everything and then remove it only where `const` is impossible.

Comment: How about using converting constructors instead of casts?  Or, better still, doing what @PaulMcKenzie suggests.

Comment: `operator SI();` -- I suggest you have a `toSI()` and a `toImperialSystem()` functions, and not the hard-to-maintain casting operators.  When the code gets more complex, even you will lose track of which function is actually called if you stick with casting operators.  Note that even the standard C++ library doesn't make big use (if any) of this -- for example, `std::string::c_str()` instead of a `const char *()` casting function is used.  Yes, those casts "look cool", but in my experience, they lead to more bugs and code going down paths you didn't expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove,

> operator float() {
> return mfeet + minch / 12.0;
> }

from your SI class.

This creates confusion in construction and casting in msvs and clang compiler.